# Service like "Opera Max" for OS X?

Tags: proxy

There is an app for Android called "Opera Max" which compresses all Internet data systemwide no matter which app you are using. It can give amazing data savings.

Is there any similar service for OS X? It would be really useful when one is on a limited data plan like a 4G hotspot.

I'm not interested in the built in compression in browsers like Chrome and Opera. I'm looking for a systemwide service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting idea, but I don't think such a service exists for OS X. There would have to be a complementary service on the other side of the internet connection to uncompress the data, which is what the Opera Max service does for Android users.

If you read the [Opera Max FAQ](http://www.opera.com/help/max/android), they write that... "We're working hard to bring Opera Max to new regions. To ensure a high-quality experience, we have to buy, ship, and set up new servers all over the world."

Comment: Good point, the whole service would be quite costly for the company supplying it. I wonder if Opera are gonna bring it to desktop platforms.